# How to update BindingSource with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, devexpress

I have some database and I get from here data (users) to gridControl (DevExpress).

When I want to add new user in other form, I want to update a gridControl, so I reload `BindingSource`, but how can I reload the new data to `BindingSource`?

```
command.ExecuteReader();
f1.gr1.BeginUpdate();
f1.grv1.Columns.Clear();

f1.gr1.DataSource = null;
f1.datas.
f1.gr1.DataSource = f1.datas;
f1.gr1.EndUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all in differnent Funtions After Saving Data to the DB call again the load method